# MySQL query to find items without matching record in JOIN is very slow

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

I've read a lot of questions about query optimization but none have helped me with this.

As setup, I have 3 tables that represent an "entry" that can have zero or more "categories".

```
> show create table entries;
CREATE TABLE `entries` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
  ...
  `name` varchar(255),
  `updated_at` timestamp NOT NULL,
  ...
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `name` (`name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB

> show create table entry_categories;
CREATE TABLE `entry_categories` (
  `ent_name` varchar(255),
  `cat_id` int(11),
  PRIMARY KEY (`ent_name`,`cat_id`),
  KEY `names` (`ent_name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB
```

(The actual "category" table doesn't come into the question.)

Editing an "entry" in the application creates a new row in the entry table -- think like the history of a wiki page -- with the same name and a newer timestamp.  I want to see how many uniquely-named Entries don't have a category, which seems really straightforward:

```
SELECT COUNT(id)
FROM entries e
LEFT JOIN entry_categories c
ON e.name=c.ent_name
WHERE c.ent_name IS NUL
GROUP BY e.name;
```

On my small dataset (about 6000 total entries, with about 4000 names, averaging about one category per named entry) this query takes over 24 seconds (!).  I've also tried

```
SELECT COUNT(id)
FROM entries e
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
  SELECT ent_name
  FROM entry_categories c
  WHERE c.ent_name = e.name
)
GROUP BY e.name;
```

with similar results.  This seems really, really slow to me, especially considering that finding entries in a single category with

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM entries e
JOIN (
  SELECT ent_name as name
  FROM entry_categories
  WHERE cat_id = 123
)c
USING (name)
GROUP BY name;
```

runs in about 120ms on the same data.  Is there a better way to find records in a table that *don't* have at least one corresponding entry in another table?

---

I'll try to transcribe the EXPLAIN results for each query:

```
> EXPLAIN {no category query};
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+-------+---------+------+------+----------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type  | possible_keys |  key  | key_len | ref  | rows |                    Extra                     |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+-------+---------+------+------+----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | e     | index | NULL          | name  |     767 | NULL | 6222 | Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | c     | index | PRIMARY,names | names |     767 | NULL | 6906 | Using where; using index; Not exists         |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+-------+---------+------+------+----------------------------------------------+

> EXPLAIN {single category query}
+----+-------------+------------+-------+---------------+-------+---------+------+--------------------------+---------------------------------+
| id | select_type |   table    | type  | possible_keys |  key  | key_len | ref  |           rows           |              Extra              |
+----+-------------+------------+-------+---------------+-------+---------+------+--------------------------+---------------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY     | <derived2> | ALL   | NULL          | NULL  | NULL    | NULL | 2850                     | Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | e          | ref   | name          | 767   | c.name  | 1    | Using where; Using index |                                 |
|  2 | DERIVED     | c          | index | NULL          | names | NULL    | 6906 | Using where; Using index |                                 |
+----+-------------+------------+-------+---------------+-------+---------+------+--------------------------+---------------------------------+
```

Comment: Why are you using entry name, rather than entry ID, to identify the entry in the entry_categories table?

Comment: Think of "entry" table rows as individual revisions of a wiki page -- the name of the page is the ID the user cares about, but we need to keep a history of changes.  There's an entry ID, but the category is applied to the "page", not one revision.

Comment: How long does the following query take: `select name, sum(e) from (select name, 1 e, 0 c from entries union all select ent_name name, 0 e, 1 c from entry_categories) s group by name having sum(c) = 0;` ?

Comment: @MarkBannister it was 1.37 seconds.  I'm a bit hazy on UNION and HAVING but if I read that correctly, it's creating a table with (entry name, e=1, c=0) and merging it with a separate table of (ent_name, e=0, c=1), such that the result is (entry name, number of entry-table rows with that name, number of entry_category rows with that name).  Is that correct?  If so, this solves my problem!  You can make an answer and I'd accept it.

Comment: Coderer: Yes - I have added that query as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
select name, sum(e) count_entries from 
(select name, 1 e, 0 c from entries 
 union all 
 select ent_name name, 0 e, 1 c from entry_categories) s 
group by name 
having sum(c) = 0
```

Comment: I tried a vaguely-similar OUTER JOIN, hoping to get a table of name plus category_id for every entry, with category_id null in rows without a category.  This took well over 2 minutes.  Your UNION takes 1.3 seconds, or as little has 200ms if I just want a count.  I don't claim to understand why but wow, what a difference!

Comment: @Coderer: Glad I could help - I suspect it's doing table scans rather than using the indexes (which can be more efficient on smaller tables), but I'm not certain; the query plan may offer further insight.

Answer (score 0):

First: remove the `names` key as it's the same as the primary key (as the `ent_name` column is the left-most in the primary key and the PK can be used to resolve the query). This should change the output of explain by using the PK in the join.

The keys you are using to join are pretty large (255 varchar column) - it is better if you can use integers for this, even if this mean introducing one more table (with the room_id, room_name mapping)

For some reason the query uses `filesort`, despite that you don't have an `order by` clause.

Can you show the explain results next to each query, and the single category query, for further diagnosis?